# TeamViewer slow on Ubuntu without monitor 16.04

Tags: 16.04, remote, teamviewer

After restarting my server without a monitor connected, TeamViewer is extremely slow. But if I restart with a monitor it runs fine. How can I get it working like normal without a monitor attached?

Answer (score 3):

Install a dummy server:

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-dummy-lts-xenial
```

Add a `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` file with the following contents:

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier  "Configured Video Device"
    Driver      "dummy"
EndSection
Section "Monitor"
    Identifier  "Configured Monitor"
    HorizSync 31.5-48.5
    VertRefresh 50-70
EndSection
Section "Screen"
    Identifier  "Default Screen"
    Monitor     "Configured Monitor"
    Device      "Configured Video Device"
    DefaultDepth 24
    SubSection "Display"
    Depth 24
    Modes "1024x800"
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

Comment: This works! However the maximum resolution is "1360x768". Changing the xorg.conf to 1920x1200 does not help.

Answer (score 2):

Adding a fake monitor fixes the problem:

```
sudo apt install xserver-xorg-video-dummy
sudo wget -P /etc/X11 https://gist.githubusercontent.com/mangoliou/ba126832f2fb8f86cc5b956355346038/raw/b6ad063711226fdd6413189ad905943750d64fd8/xorg.conf
```

Comment: I'm having issues installing the dummy sever. Did you have to do anything to get it to work?

`The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 xserver-xorg-video-dummy : Depends: xorg-video-abi-20
                            Depends: xserver-xorg-core (>= 2:1.17.99.902)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.`

Comment: `sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-dummy-lts-xenial` works but the xorg.conf doesn't seem to be working properly. Crashes X.