# Ubuntu 16.04 running excruciatingly slow when external HDDs are connected

Tags: 16.04, hard-drive, performance, usb-drive, fstab

I have been though quite a few threads here (and other forums) but have been unable to find an answer to this.

I have recently setup Ubuntu 16.06 on a Asus VivoMini U45 miniPC (Celeron N3060). Installation went fine and the OS is stable and performing quite fast as expected. This machine is to be used as a Samba fileserver (tried NFS but could not get it to work but that's another story) and a Plex server.

When I connect my two external HDDs the system slows down to halt. Simply starting terminal takes about 45 seconds and gfx rendering is frame-lagging. If the drives are removed and the pc restarted it is responding as it should. fstab shown below:

Notes: The /export/users mount is probably leftover from the attempted NFS setup, so it has been commented out.

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=8f11ce71-6e25-4ec0-824b-84387fc2af41 /boot           ext2    defaults        0       2
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-swap_1 none            swap    sw              0       0
#/home/users    /export/users   none    bind  0  0
UUID=DC666A53666A2F08   /mnt/2Tb ntfs-3g rw,nosuid,nodev,allow_other,default_permissions,uid=1000,gid=1000,umask=002,x-gvfs-show 0 0
UUID=5694066194064449 /mnt/1Tb ntfs-3g rw,nosuid,nodev,allow_other,default_permissions,uid=1000,gid=1000,umask=002,x-gvfs-show 0 0
```

I have checked for CPU throttling (s-tui and i7z) and it does not seem to be the issue both under normal operation monitoring and under stress.

Internet / LAN speeds and USB transfer rates appear to be fine (have not measured either but i have not noticed any considerable delays).

TL;DR: Ubuntu 16.04 is running very slow when USB HDDs are connected but fine when they are unplugged.

Any help on this will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This has now been resolved, on second examination, there was another variable. 
When I was plugging in the HDDS I was also unplugging the monitor which was causing the apparent frame lag and slow response from Ubuntu.

This has been resolved by installing a "dummy" monitor using xserver tools as per post [TeamViewer slow on Ubuntu without monitor 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1022093/teamviewer-slow-on-ubuntu-without-monitor-16-04)